# Tracking information with php, mysql and flash

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript

As i have small requirement regarding tracking information from different parts of a flash file using php mysql. Means in a flash game i will be having preloader part, more games button and logo inside the game. As i want to track that how many clicks are getting from these places using php mysql. Can anyone give me any ideas.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/flashTrackingIntro

Comment: Thanks for this link but i know this thing. actually i want to track into my mysql database using php.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [URLRequest](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLRequest.html)/[URLLoader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) classes of ActionScript to send a request to your website. Parse the request with PHP, extract the [GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) or [POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) variables and [insert them](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) into your database.